# CSS Overflow:auto hiding absolutely positioned child elements that exceed parent size

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position

I have a DIV that will be the width of the page but the contents may be too wide to fit. I've set up overflow-x:auto for it so that the contents are scrollable.
My problem is that I'd like to make each of the child divs expand and be visible when you hover on them but they are currently clipped if they exceed the parent div.

Here's [the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lepp23z0/)

HTML:

```
    <div class='Content'>
<div class='ImageContainer'>
    <div class='Image'>Container 1</div>
</div>
<div class='ImageContainer'>
    <div class='Image'>Container 2</div>
</div>
<div class='ImageContainer'>
    <div class='Image'>Container 3</div>
</div>
<div class='ImageContainer'>
    <div class='Image'>Container 4</div>
</div>
<div class='ImageContainer'>
    <div class='Image'>Container 5</div>
</div>
<div class='ImageContainer'>
    <div class='Image'>Container 6</div>
</div>
<div class='ImageContainer'>
    <div class='Image'>Container 7</div>
</div>
<div class='ImageContainer'>
    <div class='Image'>Container 8</div>
</div>
<div class='ImageContainer'>
    <div class='Image'>Container 9</div>
</div>
<div class='ImageContainer'>
    <div class='Image'>Container 10</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.Content {
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.ImageContainer {
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.Image {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:1;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:#AAA;
}
.Image:hover {
    left:-10px;
    top:-10px;
    right:-10px;
    bottom:-10px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Padding the "content" div is a work-around, but doesn't really fix my problem. Any CSS gurus out there with a few seconds to waste? I know this is probably simple to fix. Thanks!

Comment: You will not be able to realize this layout behavior using CSS alone, you will need some JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make the image container extend beyond the parent div by eliminating scroll bars entirely.

It's not ideal but I wasn't able to find a solution on here other than [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zyvup63g/):

```
.Content {
    text-align:center;
    margin:15px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.ImageContainer {
    position:relative;
    width:80px;
    height:150px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.Image {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:1;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:#AAA;
}
.Image:hover {
    left:-15px;
    top:-15px;
    right:-15px;
    bottom:-15px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the "overflow" properties from ".Content" and wrapping it in another class. example:

```
<div class='MainContainer'>
<div class='Content'>
    <div class='ImageContainer'>
        <div class='Image'>Container 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class='ImageContainer'>
        <div class='Image'>Container 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class='ImageContainer'>
        <div class='Image'>Container 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class='ImageContainer'>
        <div class='Image'>Container 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class='ImageContainer'>
        <div class='Image'>Container 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class='ImageContainer'>
        <div class='Image'>Container 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class='ImageContainer'>
        <div class='Image'>Container 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class='ImageContainer'>
        <div class='Image'>Container 8</div>
    </div>
    <div class='ImageContainer'>
        <div class='Image'>Container 9</div>
    </div>
    <div class='ImageContainer'>
        <div class='Image'>Container 10</div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Here I've wrapped your content in MainContainer now for the styling:

```
.MainContainer{
    width:100%;
    height:220px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}

.Content {
    margin:30px 0px;
    white-space:nowrap;
position:relative;
}
```

Check out the result here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lepp23z0/1/

Comment: I think you just linked my jsfiddle again.

Comment: I created a jsfiddle from your idea though and added a border to the maincontainer (and a margin) so you can see that it is still hiding any overflow. [See here](https://jsfiddle.net/xu1ty6yd/)